# why does require.js go inside head tag

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

According to many sources such as Yahoo Developer Network, javascript goes at the bottom of the page so web page content will display before javascript is loaded. Does putting call to require.js in the head tag will make a browser wait for the script to finish loading before displaying a page?

```
<head>
<title>My Sample Project</title>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is a bit complex; It can go in either the `<head>` or `<body>` of your page, depending on *what you're requiring* with `require.js`. Certain operations logically need to happen before the content is loaded, but most things are happy to wait.

An example of something which needs to happen before the page loads is a css pre-processor like `LESS`, this obviously needs to run in the `<head>` (in reality this should probably be pre-compiled and served as static css, but it serves as a good example) - another example would be a JavaScript template system or some kind of client side MVC system like `ember.js`

For basic presentational JavaScript it's usually safe to include it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Just a note that if you include your requirejs markup in the head element, it'll automatically inject another script tag with the async attribute for your main script.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. That's the same thing for all the scripts in the head tag. A script block parallel downloads and the browser continues rendering the page once it's finish being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of the javascript file, when it is going to be executed.

e.g.

```
<script>
  function load() {
    alert("load event!");
  }
  window.onload = load;
</script>
```

the message box will display after the page is loaded.